# Framework7 | How do I make a toggle change to darkmode

Tags: html-framework-7

Iv'e been trying to make a framework7 darkmode toggle for my new app but I cant figure out how to do it. Ive tried the click funtion on my div and I looked all over google and cant find anything that helps so anything you can tell me would be a big help.

Here's my toggle that I want to use to switch between light and dark.

```
<div style="margin-top:60px;" class="list simple-list inset">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>Dark Mode</span>
      <label class="toggle">
        <input id="toggle-dark" type="checkbox">
        <span class="toggle-icon"></span>
      </label>
    </li>
</div>
```

Here's my app.js I dont know if you need it but ive seen a lot online with the app.js so its here if you need it.

```
// Dom7
var $ = Dom7;

// Theme
var theme = 'auto';
if (document.location.search.indexOf('theme=') >= 0) {
  theme = document.location.search.split('theme=')[1].split('&')[0];
}

// Init App
var app = new Framework7({
  id: 'io.framework7.testapp',
  root: '#app',
  theme: theme,
  data: function () {
    return {
      user: {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe',
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    helloWorld: function () {
      app.dialog.alert('Hello World!');
    },
  },
  routes: routes,
  popup: {
    closeOnEscape: true,
  },
  sheet: {
    closeOnEscape: true,
  },
  popover: {
    closeOnEscape: true,
  },
  actions: {
    closeOnEscape: true,
  },
  vi: {
    placementId: 'pltd4o7ibb9rc653x14',
  },
});
```

Thank you I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to change the theme;

html

```
<li>
  <span>Dark Mode</span>
  <label class="toggle">
    <input id="toggle-dark" type="checkbox" @change="changeTheme">
    <span class="toggle-icon"></span>
  </label>
</li>
```

js

```
  changeTheme(e) {
    const el = Dom7("html");
    e.target.checked
      ? el.addClass("theme-dark")
      : el.removeClass("theme-dark");
  }
```

using Framework7 5.7.8